# Нужна помощь в тестовом задании по SQL!

Tags: sql

### Table: customers

| customer_id | customer_name | contact_name | city | country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alfreds Futterkiste | Maria Ander | Berlin | Germany |
| ------------- | --------------------- | -------------- | -------- | --------- |
| 18 | Ernst Handel | Roland Mendel | Graz | Austria |

- Підрахуйте кількість клієнтів з Лондона (London).
- Задайте тимчасову назву для результуючої колонки - `amount_of_customers`.

---

- Подсчитайте количество клиентов из Лондона (London).
- Задайте временное название для результирующей колонки - `amount_of_customers`.

Моя попытка решения:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS amount_of_customers
FROM customers
WHERE country = 'London';
```

Comment: Дядька, ну сейчас тебя размажут... три причины: русский язык, отсутствие попыток решения, ну, и то, что написано, надо вставлять кодом, а не текстом.

Comment: @S.H. Ну так ведь по делу же ж размажут, а не развлечения для...

Comment: черт побери, я тут первый раз просто, не судите строго, пожалуйста

Comment: @Макс - ну так вперед - внизу вопроса есть кнопочка "редактировать"... О, совсем другое дело!

Comment: Блин, ну это ж элементарная задача. Одно условие, одна аггрегатная функция (базовая вообще). Ну и колонку выводимую назвать.

Comment: та я понимаю, что элементарная, но решение не правильное.

Comment: Так показывай решение, добавляй его в вопрос. Попытка решения, хоть и неправильная - это совсем другое дело, чем "решите задачу за меня".

Comment: так то добавил, но сути проблемы не решает

Comment: @Макс Так всё ж у вас правильно, кроме того, что Лондон - это не страна же ;)

Comment: спасибо)
такой вареный сижу, что допускаю такие детские ошибки..

Comment: А привели бы код сразу и написали, что выводится и что должно выводиться - не было бы минусов у вопроса и недоумения у комментирующих. Ну, имейте в виду на будущее ))

Answer (score 1):

Ну это просто несерьезно, вы на уроках что делали?

Даже спя на уроке вы бы хотя-бы услышить что одно из саммых главный операторов это `SELECT` после чего вы должны выбрать колоны, после пишите `FROM` это означает из какой таблицы вы хотите взять данные, и названия самой таблицы.
Синтакс `SELECT колона1, колона2 FROM названия_таблицы`
В вашем случае `SELECT * FROM customers` - вы выбрали все данные из таблицы `customers`

Чтобы написать какое нибудь условия используеться `WHERE` и условия.
Синтакс `SELECT колона1, колона2 FROM названия_таблицы WHERE условия`.
В вашем случае `SELECT * FROM customers WHERE city ='London'` - выбрать все данные где город London.

Половина задачи уже выполненно, чтобы посчитать количество данных используеться `COUNT`.
Синтакс `SELECT COUNT(колона1) FROM названия_таблицы`
В вашем случае `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customers WHERE city ='London'` - посчитать все записи где город London

А для того чтобы дать временное названия колоны используеться `AS`.
Синтакс `SELECT колона1 AS временное_названия FROM названия_таблицы`
В вашем случае `SELECT COUNT(*) AS amount_of_customers FROM customers WHERE city ='London'` - посчитать все записи где город London с измененной названием переменной.

Слов нет ...